# Cannot compare the organisms properly with Comparable interface - Java

Tags: java, comparable

So i have a little 'Virtual World' project in Java that has a four Animals ( they extend the Organism class ). Each of those ( Antelope, Fox, Turtle, Wolf ) has a fields of Initiative, Strenght and Age ( all ints ). I want to put them in Array and then sort it with the highest Initiative on top, and if the initiative is equal on both animals - older one is higher. So to compare those, my abstract class "Organism" implemented the Comparable interface and i overrided the method compareTo, so it looks like this:

```
    @Override
public int compareTo(Organism anotherOrganism) {
    int compareValue = 0;

    if (this.getInitiative() > anotherOrganism.getInitiative()){
        compareValue = 1;
    } else if (this.getInitiative() < anotherOrganism.getInitiative()){
        compareValue = -1;
    } else if (this.getInitiative() == anotherOrganism.getInitiative()){
        if (this.getAge() > anotherOrganism.getAge()){
            compareValue = 1;
        } else {
            compareValue = -1;
        }
    }
    return compareValue;
}
```

I entered those Animals into the Array in the following order ( number in bracket is their actual Initiative )  : Fox (7) -> Turtle (1) -> Antelope (4) -> Wolf(5) and then used the

```
        Collections.sort(organismList);
```

expecting this to result in

```
 Fox, Wolf, Antelope, Turtle
```

instead of this i received

```
 Wolf, Antelope, Turtle, Fox
```

What went wrong here? Obviously the Animals have the compareTo method implemented as well ( they refer to super.compareTo from Organism )

Edit: Yeah, so with below advices saying that the code is rather good, i've removed any Initiative from the animals ( the field is left blank ) and i still get the very same output. No idea why....

Comment: I don't think there's any reason for subclasses to override `compareTo`. It would seem the problem is not within the code posted.

Comment: my proper animal class ( fox for example ) simply recalls this method from the Organism class so it looks like:
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Organism anotherOrganism) {
        return super.compareTo(anotherOrganism);
    }

Comment: If all you're doing is returning super.compare To, I'd remove the methods from the animals.

Comment: Your age comparison has a slight bug. You don't check for the case with the same age.

Answer (score 0):

I've expanded the code into a [Meal Ready to Eat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It prints the expected.

```
[Organism$1Turtle, Organism$1Antelope, Organism$1Wolf, Organism$1Fox]
```

The code:

```
import java.util.*;

abstract class Organism implements Comparable<Organism> {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        class Fox extends Organism {
            @Override public int getInitiative() {
                return 7;
            }
        }
        class Turtle extends Organism {
            @Override public int getInitiative() {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        class Antelope extends Organism {
            @Override public int getInitiative() {
                return 4;
            }
        }
        class Wolf extends Organism {
            @Override public int getInitiative() {
                return 5;
            }
        }
        List<Organism> organismList = Arrays.asList(
            new Fox(), new Turtle(), new Antelope(), new Wolf()
        );

        Collections.sort(organismList);

        System.err.println(organismList);
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName();
    }
    public abstract int getInitiative();
    public int getAge() {
        return 42;
    }
        @Override
public int compareTo(Organism anotherOrganism) {
    int compareValue = 0;

    if (this.getInitiative() > anotherOrganism.getInitiative()){
        compareValue = 1;
    } else if (this.getInitiative() < anotherOrganism.getInitiative()){
        compareValue = -1;
    } else if (this.getInitiative() == anotherOrganism.getInitiative()){
        if (this.getAge() > anotherOrganism.getAge()){
            compareValue = 1;
        } else {
            compareValue = -1;
        }
    }
    return compareValue;
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah so definately it looks like its a structure issue, not the code. Im not sure what went wrong here

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```java
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Organism> organisms = new ArrayList<>();

        // Each organism is created with initiative, strength and age
        organisms.add(new Antelope(4, 1, 1));
        organisms.add(new Fox(7, 2, 2));
        organisms.add(new Turtle(1, 3, 3));
        organisms.add(new Wolf(5, 4, 4));
        organisms.add(new Wolf(5, 4, 5));

        organisms.sort(Demo::sortByInitiative);

        for (Organism o : organisms) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }

    private static int sortByInitiative(Organism o1, Organism o2) {
        int c = Integer.compare(o2.getInitiative(), o1.getInitiative());
        if (c != 0) {
            return c;
        }
        return Integer.compare(o2.getAge(), o1.getAge());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming initiative and age member variables are public (you can replace by getters though) you can achieve your desirable sorting in one line of code

```
List<Organism> organisms = Arrays.asList(/* add your objects */);
organisms.sort(Comparator.comparing((Organism o) -> o.initiative, 
Comparator.reverseOrder()).thenComparing(o-> o.age, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

See below for a complete example

```
public class Quick {

    static class Organism{
        public String name;
        public int initiative;
        public int age;

        public Organism(String name, int initiative, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.initiative = initiative;
            this.age = age;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Organism{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", initiative=" + initiative +
                    ", age=" + age +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Organism> orgs = Arrays.asList(
                new Organism("Fox", 1, 2),
                new Organism("Ant", 1, 3),
                new Organism("Mule", 2, 2)
        );

        orgs.sort(Comparator.comparing((Organism o) -> o.initiative,
        Comparator.reverseOrder()).thenComparing(o-> o.age, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
        orgs.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

    }

}
```